# Raise an error if method's parameters do not meet certain criteria

Tags: ruby

Is it possible to prevent an object from being initialized and raise an error if some parameters passed to the initialize method don't match certain conditions?

For example, if I define a class `EvenInt` that has one attribute `x` that must be an even integer, is it possible to prevent an object of this class from being initialized, for instance, if I pass `3` as a parameter?

If so, could you quickly explain how to do so, particularly how to raise errors?

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you need to check whether the provided argument meets the criteria and if yes - do whatever the method should do, otherwise raise the exception:

```
class EventInt
  def initialize(x)
    if x.is_a?(Integer) && x.even?
      @x = x
    else
      raise 'Argument should be an even integer'
    end
  end
end

EventInt.new(1)
#=> RuntimeError: Argument should be an even integer
EventInt.new(1.1)
#=> RuntimeError: Argument should be an even integer
EventInt.new(1.2)
#=> RuntimeError: Argument should be an even integer
EventInt.new(2)
#=> #<A:0x00007fca4c9a0498 @even_int=2>
```

Actually, it would make more sense to return a specific error, namely `ArgumentError`:

```
raise ArgumentError, 'Argument should be an even integer'
```

Or, if you want to have your custom error class, you could do the following:

```
NotEvenIntegerArgumentError = Class.new(ArgumentError)
```

and then in `initialize`:

```
raise NotEvenIntegerArgumentError, 'Argument should be an even integer'
```

Or, if you want, you can set up a default exception message in your exception class. The whole code would look as follows

```
class EventInt
  NotEvenIntegerArgumentError = Class.new(ArgumentError) do
    def message
      'Argument should be an even integer'
    end
  end

  def initialize(x)
    if x.is_a?(Integer) && x.even?
      @x = x
    else
      raise NotEvenIntegerArgumentError
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: This is the best answer so as to avoid a `NoMethodError` for `#even?` or `#odd?` when given an object that does not have these methods and to avoid allowing an object that is not an `Integer` but has implemented these methods to pass through. My only thought though is this should raise an `ArgumentError` as that is the actual issue rather than a `RuntimeError` which is not very explicit. Some explanation would be nice as well

Comment: @engineersmnky true that, edited the answer with these edits :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of corse. Something like this

```
class EvenInteger
  def initialize(number)
    if number.odd?
      raise StandardError
    end
    @value = number
  end

  attr_reader :value
end

EvenInteger.new(3)
=> StandardError (StandardError)
EvenInteger.new(4).value
=> 4
```

Or maybe you can raise an `ArgumentError` or even define your specific subclass of `StandardError`.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just raise an error in the `initialize` method:

```
class EnventInt
  def initialize(x)
    @x = x

    raise ArgumentError, "x must be even" unless @x.even?
  end
end
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use Ruby's `raise` method to raise an error, furthermore, you also could writing a message to tell user why this happened.

```
class EvenInt
  attr_reader :x
  def initialize(integer)
    raise ArgumentError, "Number shoud be even." unless integer.even?
    @x = integer
  end
end
```

If you try:

```
> EvenInt.new(2)
=> #<EvenInt:0x00007fbc81019830 @x=2>

> EvenInt.new(3)
Traceback ......
......
ArgumentError (Number shoud be even.)
```

The `ArgumentError` indicates the specific error type which you could specify. Then you leave a message to user why this was wrong.